# HTML is not aligning on the right side of the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to copy the HTML `table` part into the Right side of the form. But when I add the `td's` it gets dealigned.

Here is my HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr style="width: 50%">
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Aggregate Name:
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAggrName" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Confirm Party:
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmParty1" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Agreement Amt Payable
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgreAmtPay" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Land Agrregate Payable
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtlandAggPay" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Confirm Party
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmParty2" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Total Land Value
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLandValue" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Stamp Duty
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStampDuty" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Registration Fees
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegisFees" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Legal Fees
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLegalFees" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Other Expenses
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOthExp" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Total =
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; width: 10%; text-align: left;
            font-size: 120%;">
            Grand Total =
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrandTotal" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below is the screenshot as what it looks like

[image: HTML part]

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/8a2umv2z/1/) ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: yes almost, but there should be **2 td in 1 tr**.. Like name and its control

Comment: So you want like, *label* and its *control* and again repeat the same on their right?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: yes exactly like that..

Comment: then for a better *Dom* structure  you should make **4 td in 1 tr** otherwise they'll surely mis-aligned ultimately.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: yeah u r right..Please help me with making this.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I have created a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/8a2umv2z/3) for your desired structure.

And for a better view and a valid **HTML** as per your requirements you need to follow **DOM** as:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; text-align: left;
        font-size: 120%; width: 20%; ">
            Aggregate Name:
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left; width: 30%;">
            <input type="text" style="width: 90%" />
        </td>
        <td class="label" style="font-family: Courier New; text-align: left;
        font-size: 120%; width: 20%; ">
            Aggregate Name:
        </td>
        <td class="field" style="text-align: left; width: 30%;">
            <input type="text" style="width: 90%" />
        </td>
    </tr>
   ...
```

Comment: The right hand side has less td's . so the background is coming as white. like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/juH9o.png What should I write to make it as that of left background

Comment: have you fixed the `width` of your `table` or the container of your `table` make both to `100%` only after that it will cover the full width of the screen. Check Fiddle in my answer I have updated it for `bgcolor`

Comment: yes, i have added the width, but still not getting the background. Here is my fiddle Can u update on this. https://jsfiddle.net/g0L0gcmf/

Comment: hi, are u their? need one small help related to this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121533/discussion-between-vivekkupadhyay-and-stack).

Answer (score 0):

Put your whole table in div with ID and resize it's width to 50% then move your div to right by CSS tag:
Here is example:

```
    table-right{
width: 500px;
margin-left: 400px;
}
```